# Error adding "Invoice ID" to sales grid

Tags: magento-1.9, sales, order-grid

I added in the invoice ID to the order grid using the code below which shows them fine! However when I try and search by Invoice ID I get the following error. Any help is appreciated!

BUMP: Still stuck!

```
a:5:{i:0;s:835:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'invoice_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `main_table`.*, `sales_flat_invoice`.`increment_id` AS `invoice_id`, COALESCE(`_table_customer_rba_account`.`value`,`_table_guest_customer_rba_account`.`customer_rba_account`) AS `customer_rba_account` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_invoice` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_invoice.order_id
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `_table_customer_rba_account` ON _table_customer_rba_account.entity_id = main_table.customer_id  AND _table_customer_rba_account.attribute_id = 289
 LEFT JOIN `am_customerattr_guest` AS `_table_guest_customer_rba_account` ON _table_guest_customer_rba_account.order_id = main_table.entity_id WHERE (`invoice_id` LIKE '%100050%')) AS `a`";i:1;s:6824:"#0
```

My code below:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_invoice', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_invoice.order_id', 'increment_id as invoice_id');
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

      $this->addColumn('invoice_id', array(
          'header'=> $this->__('Invoice'),
          'width' => '80px',
          'type'  => 'text',
          'index' => 'invoice_id',
      ));

etc...
```

Comment: is solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

In `$this->addColumn('invoice_id', array(`  section, you need to add attribute 
 `filter_index`.  Like

```
  $this->addColumn('invoice_id', array(
      'header'=> $this->__('Invoice'),
      'width' => '80px',
      'type'  => 'text',
      'index' => 'invoice_id',
      'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_invoice.increment_id',
  ));
```

Hopes it works fine.